# Applying conditions inside and outside a probability.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For random variables $X_n$ for $n\in \mathbb N$ and a random variable $X$, consider the statements

(A) $P(X_n=X\text{ for all }n\in \mathbb N)=1$;

(B) $P(X_n=X)=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

I thought A and B were equivalent statements, but instead A implies B. Why is this the case?

Comment: (Adam, I edited your post to use only normal text characters, and so that each mathematical expression is not split across multiple math environments `$...$`. A good reference is [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).)

Answer (score 1):

They are indeed equivalent! This follows from the fact that a countable union of events of probability $0$ has probability $0$. (Consider the events $(X_n \neq X)$).

Comment: Thank you! I was getting very confused. There must be a mistake in the material I'm reading.

Comment: @AdamToner I noticed that you have just joined MSE. Welcome! Do you know that if you are happy with an answer you can conisder approving it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer?